# How to generate soft lockup in Linux Kernel and how to verify?

Tags: linux, reboot, kernel

I was testing soft lockup recovery procedure of Linux Kernel. I set /proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_panic to 1.

And I created a Kernel module as described in the link below. https://github.com/saiyamd/softlockup_test

When I inserted the module, my linux system is rebooting after hang up for short time. If I set /proc/sys/kernel/softloup_panic to 0. My linux system remains as hang and never reboot. It seems the scheme of rebooting when soft lockup occur works, but I cannot see the log message like "BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 20s!".

Even though it reboots, I'm not really sure this is the right test procedure for generating soft lockup and recovery procedure from the soft lockup.

Please let me know if I'm doing wrong or if you see any my misunderstanding. Thanks,

Comment: Can you use dmesg to show the kernel log when system hang?

Answer (score 0):

### `softlockup_panic on`

"Recovery" here includes the kernel panicking and rebooting the system. A reboot is expected since the setting is `on`.

### `softlockup_panic off`

You generated a softlockup correctly. Under *normal* circumstances you would see a message similar to "BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 20s!". The reason you are not seeing anything is due to the fact that your kernel module is calling **printk in a tight loop**. Assuming you can even use the system under such a high IO load, your module will be competing with other kernel threads for logging. That's why you don't see any softlockup messages.

---

**Suggested solution:** update your infinite loop to use a counter variable to print messages only every X iterations, where X is at least 10,000,000 (<- somewhat arbitrary). The below example relies on unsigned integer overflow.

```
unsigned int i;
for (i=0; ; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        printk("message\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a serial console, then you can use netconsole to trace the softlock.

Syntax of netconsole:

```
netconsole=<LOCAL_PORT>@<SENDER_IP_ADDRESS>/<SENDER_INTERFACE>,<REMOTE_PORT>@<RECEIVER_IP_ADDRESS>/<STEP_1_MAC_ADDRESS>
```

1. Add

   ```
   netconsole netconsole=6666@192.168.43.11/enp0s3,6666@192.168.43.141/14:ab:c5:83:50:36 loglevel=8
   ```

   in boot arg. 
   Or

   ```
   sudo modprobe netconsole netconsole="6666@192.168.43.11/enp0s3,6666@192.168.43.141/14:ab:c5:83:50:36"
   ```

   at run time.
   Or

   ```
   sudo modprobe netconsole netconsole="6666@/enp0s3,6666@192.168.43.141/" at run time.
   ```
2. After booting, set

   ```
   dmesg -n 8
   ```

   (To get regular kernel dmesg)
3. At the receiver side, run

   ```
   netcat -l -u 6666
   ```

**Note :**
Comment `printk` from the while(1) loop, otherwise console will be flooded with print. After 20 or more seconds, you will see the softlock message. Like below

> watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [softlockup_thre:3444]
>   while(1) {
>       printk(KERN_INFO "%s:%d\n",**func**,**LINE**);
>   }